# How I do Static page in Vue js with full-featured Webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-material

I'm using:
- full-featured Webpack.
- vue-material (material design)

My app is a SPA (Single Page App).

I need to create a home page with marketing and area to login and link to create a new user.
In this initial page I do not need the Toolbar, Sidenav, etc ...

In this page I need SEO.

I thought of something hybrid... SPA + some pages.

Should I create a page (html) in static folder? I do not know how to configure the route for this ...

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: have you thought about which backend you will be using?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple strategies for this.

One could be to use [Server-Side Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) as explained in vue js documentaiton which is quite easy to understand.

The other one would be to have a static html page which will be the entry point to your app. It will be SEO optimized and you will have a call to action button that will redirect to your actual vuejs app. So in your webserver the url https://example.org redirects to your static page, and when you click on the link, it will redirect you to https://example.org/app which would be the entrypoint of your vuejs app.